# Get touch location on map

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am using following code to find latitude and longitude of touch location on map-

```
-(void)handlePressRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    for (PointAnnotation *ann in [mMapview annotations]) {
        if ([ann isKindOfClass:[PointAnnotation class]]) {
            [mMapview removeAnnotation:ann];
        }
    }
    [mMapview removeAnnotations:[mMapview annotations]];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:mMapview];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate =
    [mMapview convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:gestureRecognizer.view];
    if (gpsLocation != nil) {
        gpsLocation = nil;
    }
    gpsLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:touchMapCoordinate.latitude longitude:touchMapCoordinate.longitude];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showLoadingView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.001];
    [self performSelector:@selector(getGoogleAddressFromLocation:) withObject:gpsLocation afterDelay:0.1];


}
```

And I am passing these lat/long to google API to find address but google giving me wrong location and address.

Here is the screen shot-

[image]

Please help to find out this problem.

Comment: You can use the delegate method - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

Comment: What is GMSMapView ? There is no this type of delegate method in MKMap class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following code from google map SDK to get the tap location-

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);

    [mMapview clear];
    gpsLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];

}
```

And with following code I am dropping the pin on that location-

```
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];

    marker.title = [responseDict valueForKey:@"address"];
    marker.snippet = [responseDict valueForKey:@"country"];
    self.addressString = [responseDict valueForKey:@"address"];
    marker.position = gpsLocation.coordinate;

    marker.map = mMapview;
    [mMapview setSelectedMarker:marker];
```

with mapkit, google was not giving me the right tap location but with google map its working like a charm.

Comment: did you have any Example :-)